# Is there a way to find the definition of a class or function quickly in ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my project, there are several packages and some classes use inheritance... Is there a way to quickly find class and function instead of open all the related source files one by one in ROS?...........
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191663/is-there-a-way-to-find-the-definition-of-a-class-or-function-quickly-in-ros?/) by [guodi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4544/guodi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2014-09-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, this is not a ROS specific problem, but you could use an IDE such as [Eclipse](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs) to help you with that.

In Eclipse, you can set the mouse over a function name or a class name and right click -> Open Definition to open the file where the name that you are highlighting is defined.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2014-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3